# ASP .NET with MySQL - DeleteCommand syntax not working

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Working on setting up a SqlDataSource connecting MySQL database to a ASP .NET GridView.

The Delete Command is:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM troutetracking WHERE id=?id"
```

The Delete parameter is:

```
<DeleteParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="id"  Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

When I run a delete link on the Gridview the following error message appears:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '?id' must be defined.

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog ran into a similar issue:

[link text](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html)

What I needed to do was update the connection to string to contain "Allow User Variables=True".

I did this by using the 'Advanced' button when setting up the data source.

The delete query also needed to be tweaked to be:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM troutetracking WHERE id=@id"
```

Answer (score 1):

That is covered in [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand.aspx):

> Because different database products
>   use different varieties of SQL, the
>   syntax of the SQL string depends on
>   the current ADO.NET provider being
>   used, which is identified by the
>   [ProviderName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.providername.aspx) property. If the SQL
>   string is a parameterized query or
>   command, the syntax of the parameter
>   also depends on the ADO.NET provider
>   being used. For example, if the
>   provider is the [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx),
>   which is the default provider for the
>   [SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) class, the syntax
>   of the parameter is '@parameterName'.
>   However, if the provider is set to the
>   [System.Data.Odbc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.aspx) or
>   [System.Data.OleDb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.aspx), the
>   placeholder of the parameter is '?'.
>   For more information about
>   parameterized SQL queries and
>   commands, see [Using Parameters with
>   the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Remy.

What is confusing me is that for a UPDATE query the ?id syntax is used but for the DELETE query the ?id doesn't work.

Comment: The syntax should be the same for both, as it is based on what SQL provider is being used, not what kind of SQL statement is being executed.